# vb.net dynamically create checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am trying to figure out how to go about creating dynamic checkboxes on my form when I do not know exactly how many boxes I will need.

The problem is that I do not know how to DIM more than one object. This is my code for creating one checkbox

```
Dim checkBox As New CheckBox()

Form1.Controls.Add(checkBox)
checkBox.Location = New Point(10, 10)
checkBox.Text = "testing"
checkBox.Checked = True
checkBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
```

It works just fine but i am unable to add more than one checkBox without having to do this:

```
Dim checkBox As New CheckBox()
Dim checkBox2 As New CheckBox()

Form1.Controls.Add(checkBox)
checkBox.Location = New Point(10, 10)
checkBox.Text = "testing"
checkBox.Checked = True
checkBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)

Form1.Controls.Add(checkBox2)
checkBox2.Location = New Point(40, 10)
checkBox2.Text = "testing2"
checkBox2.Checked = True
checkBox2.Size = New Size(100, 20)
```

etc...

Is there a way to dim more than 1 checkbox instead of having to write multiple dim statements for each checkBoxe?

**Sorry maybe i should say this..**

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
 dim checkBox() as CheckBox

 do until i = 50
    Form1.Controls.Add(checkBox(i))
    checkBox(i).Location = New Point(10, 10)
    checkBox(i).Text = "testing " & i
    checkBox(i).Checked = True
    checkBox(i).Size = New Size(100, 20)
    i += 1
 loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the only items that are different and not calculated between the `CheckBox` instances is the text.  If so then you could just use the following code to add a set of `CheckBox` instances based off of a list of `String`'s.

```
Dim data as String() = New String() { "testing", "testing2" }
Dim offset = 10
For Each cur in data 
  Dim checkBox = new CheckBox()
  Form1.Controls.Add(checkBox)
  checkBox.Location = New Point(offset, 10)
  checkBox.Text = cur
  checkBox.Checked = True
  checkBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
  offset = offset + 30
Next
```

Comment: Thats what i am looking for, however, it only loops once in your example when it should loop twice?

Comment: @StealthRT, it looks for every value in the `data` array.

Comment: Correct, and it does say that data = 2 but it only has one checkbox on the form (testing) when it should have 2?

Comment: @StealthRT its likely the second checkbox is off the screen or just hidden below hthe other one.  Try changing the offset values or making the form bigger to see the other check boxes.

Comment: Ah yes, i didnt have a big enough number (i set it to 50 the first time. Now 150 and it shows up). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a loop, including the new statement but varing the position.

You could also clone the object, maybe with performance penalties ... Sorry but don't know Vb.net, I will give you the c# code hoping it will be similar. I think this it is not the best solution for your case (a loop will do the trick), but maybe it will be for someone with a similar but more generic problem.

```
CheckBox CB2 = (CheckBox)CloneObject(CheckBox1);
```

//change the location here...
    Form1.Controls.Add(checkBoxCB2  )

```
private object CloneObject(object o)
{
   Type t = o.GetType();
   PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

   Object p = t.InvokeMember("", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, o, null);

   foreach(PropertyInfo pi in properties)
      {
         if(pi.CanWrite)
           {
              pi.SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(o, null), null);
           }
      }

   return p;
}
```