# Property selecteditem is readonly for RadioButtonList

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, properties, radio-button

I have the error `Property selecteditem is readonly` when I dynamically create a radio button list like this:

```
Dim DDL As New DropDownList
Dim RBL As New RadioButtonList
Dim CBL As New CheckBoxList

DDL.ID = "DDL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
RBL.ID = "RBL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
CBL.ID = "CBL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType

If ProductType = "General" Or (CategorySelected = "KC 2.1 (retractor without webbing)" And ProductType = "KC2.1" Or ProductType = "Webbing") Or
(CategorySelected = "KC 2.1 Seatbelt)" And ProductType = "KC2.1") Then

    DDL.Visible = False
    RBL.Visible = False
    CBL.Visible = False

    DDL.SelectedItem = True
    RBL.SelectedItem = True
    CBL.SelectedItem = True

End If
```

On these 3 lines of code:

```
DDL.SelectedItem = True
RBL.SelectedItem = True
CBL.SelectedItem = True
```

the error is displayed. I have to create a table with RadioButtonList or DropDownList or CheckBoxList where the user select items, but I want some button to have a pre-selected value and doesn't display. I want that for when I read all buttons selected.

Comment: A RadioButtonList is for ASP.NET, but your question is tagged "winforms". Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Have been edited, i want for vb.net forms

Comment: `SelectedItem` is _which_ item that is currently selected. You cannot set it to a Boolean value. I suggest you read up on the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, i understand that but how i checked my value?

Comment: `SelectedItem.Selected = True`? Or `RBL.Items(item index).Selected = True`.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which do you want to select? My last example would do it. `SelectedItem` only works if you have focused an item. See my last example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107548/discussion-between-vladut-and-visual-vincent).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you make your `control` not visible just before you are trying to select them.

Change these to `true`:

```
DDL.Visible = False
RBL.Visible = False
CBL.Visible = False
```

On top of that you can have only one `radio button` within `control` selected at the time, so this is kind of pointless:

```
DDL.SelectedItem = True
RBL.SelectedItem = True
CBL.SelectedItem = True
```

Update:

```
Dim DDL As New DropDownList
```

Above cannot be checked

```
Dim RBL As New RadioButtonList
```

I believe first will be checked

I just realized that this you attempt to create these `controls`. You cannot check, uncheck `controls` before you actually `add` them. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620847/vb-net-dynamicly-create-checkboxes) may help you

Comment: You mean you are still getting error on 'DDL.SelectedItem = True' ?

Comment: When there is only one radio button in some control it is always read only since it cannot be unselected. I think you are creating them wrongly or you want to use check boxes instead.

Comment: I want to my DDL.ID to be selected when i open my page

Comment: If you get rid off these lins whats happens: DDL.SelectedItem = True
RBL.SelectedItem = True
CBL.SelectedItem = True?

Comment: If i create a single DDL work with DDL.checked = true, but with dynamically buttons doesn't work

Comment: My declaration is exactly